# LDAP connection with PHP web-application

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

We have a web-application, hosted externally. One client now asks for a SSO (single sign on) solution and suggested a LDAP link with our web-application.

Our website uses PHP. We prefer not to use something like VPN, but we have no experience at all with this stuff.  Is it possible to use Windows authentication and somehow automatically login into our web application?

Any suggestions?

Comment: depends on your webserver. What do you use? Apache? IIS?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using NTLM authentication, but tying that to Windows credentials, is Internet Explorer spesific behaviour, and NTLM isn't that well supported in all browsers. I would reccomend you rather have an ldap authentication over ssl to your AD, and have a regular basic auth box pop up instead.

You then use PHP to bind with LDAP using the credentials supplied to determine if they're valid or not.